# Dataflow Runner - Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I load data from BigQuery using `Read(BigQuerySource(query="...", use_standard_sql=True))` in pipeline. On Cloud Dataflow, after about 3 minutes of run time, it will log an INFO of Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token every few seconds until the end of job. How to fix it?[image][image]

Comment: This seems to be part of the regular oauth2 flow. The `access_token` used to have access to the resources server has an expiration time which is refreshed automatically by the client. The severity of the logging is `INFO` as well so it's not a bug or an error you need to worry about.

Comment: Alright. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The same issue also affects GCS access. This is being tracked in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2264